# Merging the results of 2 REST calls in a dataTable

Tags: list, rest, datatable

I am trying to add results from two REST calls, into one Data Tables view. I am getting just one of the Rest calls results shown.

```
//'use strict';
var appweburl;
var hostweburl;
var results;
var allResults = [];



$(document).ready(function () {

    hostweburl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("SPHostUrl"));
    appweburl =decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("SPAppWebUrl"));

    var scriptbase = hostweburl + "/_layouts/15/";// Load the js files and continue to the successHandler
   // $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.RequestExecutor.js", execCrossDomainRequest);

    $.when(
        execCrossDomainRequest()
        ).done(function () {
            InitData();
        }
        ).fail(
        function () {
            console.log("feil");
        }
        );

});


function execCrossDomainRequest() {
    var defer = $.Deferred();

    var executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(appweburl);
    executor.executeAsync(
        {
            url: "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Ansatte')/items?$select=Title",
            method: "GET",
            headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
            success: successHandler,
            error: errorHandler
        }
    );

 executor.executeAsync(
        {
            url: "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Kunder')/items?$select=Title",
            method: "GET",
            headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
            success: successHandler,
            error: errorHandler
        }
    );

    function successHandler(a) {
        var jsonObject = JSON.parse(a.body);
        results = jsonObject.d.results;

        if (allResults.length > 0)
            allResults = allResults.concat(results);

        else
            allResults = results;
        defer.resolve();
    }

    function errorHandler(data, errorCode, errorMessage) {
        alert("Could not complete cross-domain call: " + errorMessage);
        defer.reject();
    };
    return defer;
};


function InitData() {
    console.log(allResults);
    $('#example').DataTable({
        data:allResults ,
        columns: [
                    { data: "Title" }
        ]
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

To merge data of two lists in a datatable, i have modified the above code so that it will work:

```
//'use strict';
var appweburl;
var hostweburl;
var results;
var allResults = [];



$(document).ready(function () {

    hostweburl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("SPHostUrl"));
    appweburl =decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("SPAppWebUrl"));

    var scriptbase = hostweburl + "/_layouts/15/";// Load the js files and continue to the successHandler
   // $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.RequestExecutor.js", execCrossDomainRequest);

    execCrossDomainRequest();

});


function execCrossDomainRequest() {

    var call1 = $.ajax({
      url: "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Ansatte')/items?$select=Title",
            method: "GET",
            headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
            success: successHandler,
            error: errorHandler
   });

    var call2 = $.ajax({
            url: "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Kunder')/items?$select=Title",
            method: "GET",
            headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
            success: successHandler,
            error: errorHandler

   });

    function successHandler(a) {
        var jsonObject = JSON.parse(a.body);
        results = jsonObject.d.results;

        if (allResults.length > 0)
            allResults = allResults.concat(results);

        else
            allResults = results;        
    }

    function errorHandler(data, errorCode, errorMessage) {
        console.log("Could not complete cross-domain call: " + errorMessage);        
    };


    // When both Ajax requests were successful
   $.when(call1, call2).done(function(a1, a2){
      console.log(allResults);
    $('#example').DataTable({
        data:allResults ,
        columns: [
                    { data: "Title" }
        ]
    });
   });  
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not reduce it to 1 query like so?

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/_api/web/lists/items?$filter=Title eq 'Kunder' or Title eq 'Ansatte'&$select=Title",
    method: "GET",
    headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
    success: successHandler,
    error: errorHandler
});
```